# Difference of data extension "required" and "nullable" attribute in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, required-field

When creating a Data Extension in *Contact builder > Data extension*, the field attribute **required** is available except primary key. When creating a Data Extension in *Email Studio > Subscribers > Data Extension*, the field attribute **nullable** is available except primary key.

My question is: If I **check the attribute nullable** in Email Studio, is it the same as **not checking the attribute required** in Contact Builder and vice versa? Or are there other factors I need to take in consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are actually exactly the same option - and it appears ([judging from their documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_new_data_extension/)) that both will display 'required' sometime in the future and nullable will no longer be used.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation

**Primary Key** - Determines whether the system considers field to be the primary key of the table

If you select this checkbox, the system requires that the value in this field be unique so it can use this field to uniquely identify a row. If you select this checkbox for more than one column, then the combination of the values in the columns must be unique

If you do not select this checkbox, the system does not require the value in this field to be unique.

**Nullable** - Determines whether this column can be empty

If you select this checkbox, you can import a NULL (empty) value for this column.

If you do not select this checkbox and you try to import a NULL value for this column, the system will respond as you specify in the Skip Rows with Bad Data field on the import definition